# SignalR connection lost when android device sleeps

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, signalr

I have an MVC 4 application with SignalR connected to many Android tablets simultaneously. When the devices go to sleep, some of the connections are lost and some are maintained, seemingly with no pattern.

I have the following code on the view to attempt to restart the connection upon disconnect:

```
    $.connection.hub.disconnected( function () {
        setTimeout( function () {
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 5000);
    });
```

I also have the following lines in the Application_Start() method:

```
    GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours( 6 );
    GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours( 6 );
```

I understand that 6 hours is excessive, this was simply done to try to ensure that the connection would never timeout during testing.

I also have the tablets set to maintain Wi-Fi connection during sleep.

However, when the tablets are put to sleep, then awoken just a few minutes later, some connections will still be active, while others will not.

How can I ensure that the SignalR connection will either be maintained or restarted when the devices come back from sleep?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have worked out a solution that has been working.

For whatever reason, the Android tablets are never firing the $.connection.hub.disconnected() function.

Setting the following values in the Application_Start() method fixed the issue

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours( 3 );
GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours( 3 );
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 10 );
```

These values are set very large, but I have to have both the DisconnectTimeout and the ConnectionTimeout larger than the amount of time that the device is asleep. The KeepAlive simply has to be small enough to fire within a reasonable time after waking up.

I'm running this application in a controlled environment, so this works alright, but I'm sure isn't the ideal solution

Comment: Seems like a terrible idea. Especially since you'll never raise disconnect on the server (only after 3 hours). Since the server isn't cleaning up connections, you could easily flood it and it would run out of memory.

Comment: I agree, but like I said, this will only be running in a controlled environment where I know exactly how many connections are going to exist. I would certainly prefer that the tablets reconnect when they come back from sleep, but no solution I found would work 100% of the time

Comment: Great. If you're 100% aware of the implications then that's fine.

Answer (score 4):

The following code from your question seems to be the right way to go about restarting SignalR connections when the devices come back from sleep:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected( function () {
    setTimeout( function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000);
});
```

The ConnectionTimeout configuration doesn't need to be changed for your purposes. The ConnectionTimeout is used almost exclusively by the long-polling transport to decide how long to wait for a new message before closing the current poll and repolling. This defaults to 110 seconds because a lot of proxies will kill pending HTTP requests over 2 minutes old.

Upping the DisconnectTimeout to 6 hours is definitely excessive as you suggest. It will cause the server to keep lost connections in memory for six hours.

[This article on SignalR's connection lifetime](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#timeoutkeepalive) should provide more insight if you haven't already read it.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that page and haven't been able to find any solutions as of yet. The frustrating thing is that I'm testing the connection on 12 devices simultaneously and some come back and others do not. And it's different devices each time.

Comment: Is $.connection.hub.start(); getting called every five seconds on the devices that don't come back?

Comment: I've set up an alert to fire inside the setTimeout() function and it isn't appearing. As far as I can tell the devices that don't come back are never hearing the hub.disconnected() event.

Comment: Can you determine which state the inactive clients, e.g. connected, reconnecting or disconnected, and what transports they are using? I would suggest enabling client side logging so you can get a better idea of what's happening. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging

Comment: The reconnecting event gets fired whenever the client notices that its connection to the server is dead. By default, the client should automatically try reconnecting for 30 seconds. If the client doesn't successfully reconnect within 30 seconds, the disconnected event will get fired. Calling hub.start() while the connection is reconnecting (or is in any state other than disconnected) won't do anything. You could first call hub.stop() and then hub.start() in reconnecting() if you really want to manually restart the connection as soon as the reconnecting event fires.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in SignalR (version 2.0.1 and below) in which when the disconnected event is fired after the client was connected once, the status stays as connected or connecting (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2554 - solved in version 2.0.2).

You can bypass this by triggering the restart in a timeout:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () {
                console.log('Connection establish! Now lets take over the world.');
                // DO STUFF HERE
            });
    }, 10000);
});
```